# GoLang Gin Framework Status Code Without Message Body

Tags: go, go-gin

I'm using GoLang and Gin Framework.

I need to respond for REST API call with 204 response code without message body.

How it is to do properly?

What I could find by digging the source code

```
c.JSON(204, "")
```

But server throws error at such case:

Error #01: http: request method or response status code does not allow body 
     Meta: []

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use `c.AbortWithStatus(204)`, with the one caveat that when you use abort, the rest of pending handlers will never be called for that request.

Or, you could do:

```
c.Writer.WriteHeader(204)
```

and let your program continue normally (but making sure not to write out anything else)

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at Abort but didn't find it nice enough for that purpose. I like second solution! Thanks!

Comment: Also there's now (I don't know if that's recent or not) a c.Status(code) method.

Answer (score 21):

adding on @depado comments,

`c.Status(http.StatusNoContent)` is the simplest way to achieve this.
Works with `gin v1.6.3`

Answer (score 2):

up to now, the function [Abort's prototype](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Abort) is

```
 func (c *Context) Abort()
```

you can use [AbortWithStatus](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.AbortWithStatus) instead `c.AbortWithStatus(204)`, whose prototype is

```
 func (c *Context) AbortWithStatus(code int)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using built in render function:

```
c.Render(http.StatusOK, render.Data{})
```